# BasicDataSource not finding postgresql or postgis jdbc drivers

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, postgis

I'm trying to add a BasicDataSource to a new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.  When I create the new dataSource like so:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database" />
    <property name="username" value="XXXXX" />
    <property name="password" value="XXXXX" />
</bean>
```

And add it to the entitiyManagerFactory

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

The error I'm getting is that it's can't find the JDBC driver:

```
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure] HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
```

I have the jar being loaded via maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1103-jdbc3</version>
</dependency>
```

and mavens added to my classpath

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

So I'm wondering what am I missing? I can see that the driver is available from the maven dependencies library, but it never finds it when starting up.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: `jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://localhost:5432/database` needs to be `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database` PostGIS is just an extension to Postgres, there is no change to the JDBC URL for that.

Comment: I made the edit to the question above, unfortunately that doesn't make a difference since it looks at the driver first and never gets to checking the connection aspect... it could be commented out and still throw the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is created by Eclipse and poor maven management on my end.  I built the war manually and noticed that 2 different postgresql jars were being loaded into the war, an older version from Hibernate spatial and a newer version I was loading via maven (this can also be viewed by running view tree command with maven).  After removing the spatial version I had to manually run maven build war and manually add the library to tomcat. I suspect there was some residue being left somewhere that a normal project clean and maven update weren't repairing.  Once all the residue was cleaned up I was able to start the project just fine in eclipse and the library was found.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a maven caching issue ...first try and updated to a new version and see if that resolves the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

Also is this just a standalone application or are you running it in a container Eg JBoss environment ?

Comment: It's just a standalone application... putting on the new version didn't fix the problem.

Comment: what happens when you run the following in the command line: `mvn clean install`